# Memory leak: self.tableView.backgroundView

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

Could someone give me some advice why I have a memory leak associated to this line:

[image]

Comment: Please post code, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Are you forgetting to release `self.tableView.backgroundView`? We need to see the rest of your code, not just a picture of part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the warning from Build and Analyze, you'll notice that the warning actually applies to line 38 of your code, not line 39, on which the message is being shown.

On line 38 you call `alloc`, that is, you allocate memory for a `UIImageView`.

Every `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, and `retain` requires a matching `release` or `autorelease`. So, the compiler is warning you that you have called `alloc` but haven't called  a corresponding `release` anywhere.

You can add an `autorelease` to line 38 like so:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_01.jpg"]] autorelease];
```

If you don't want to use `autorelease` then you can use something like this:

```
UImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_01.jpg"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = bgImage;
[bgImage release];
```

The only real difference is that `autorelease` waits until the end of the run loop when the autorelease pool drains, whereas calling `release` will potentially release the memory sooner.

Comment: To add some clarity, the accessors used are basically calling `[[self tableView] setBackgroundView: bgImage]` (in the code above).  Understanding that the compiler turns those into message sends will reduce the confusion on when to retain or release an object. In this case, `backgroundView` is a retained property on the `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIImageView` on line 38 is leaking.  You should add `autorelease`, like so:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_01.jpg"]] autorelease];
```